# using resValue from applicationVariants.all

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

Has anyone used resValue to set values while iterating through each variant?
Couldn't get something like this to work

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    //none of these work
    variant.mergedFLavor.setResValue("integer","key","value")
    variant.mergedFlavor.resValue "integer", "key", "value"
}
```

I have the following variant structure:

```
buildTypes{
    debug {...}
    stage {...}
    release{...}
}
productFlavors {
    flavorDimensions "country", "store"

    uk {
        flavorDimension "country"
    }
    us {
        flavorDimension "country"
    }

    amazon {
        flavorDimension "store"
    }
    google {
        flavorDimension "store"
    }
}
```

I was looking to setting a tracking_id for each [country] where build type is release. And setting a unique code for each [country]+[store] combination.
I know the country/store code could be done using resource files in the following directories:

```
src/ukAmazon/res
src/ukGoogle/res
src/usAmazon/res
src/usGoogle/res
```

And tracking id in directories:

```
src/ukAmazonRelease/res
src/ukGoogleRelease/res
src/usAmazonRelease/res
src/usGoogleRelease/res
```

But it would be nice to keep everything in script and avoid duplicating res files. It will start getting even messier when more countries come in.

Answer (score 2):

For someone who still feel confused, just modify your script to something like below and it will work:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.resValue "integer", "key", "value"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67416

So it looks like it's not there yet. There is a hacky workaround mentioned.